# Is there an issue with this Laurel tree?

Tags: trees

I have three Laurel trees that were planted about 5 months ago but I’d say they’re maybe three years old, they’re about eleven feet high and lately I’ve noticed on the lower branches the leaves are a bit curly. Also there are some yellow leaves on the plant. It has sprouted flowers but they haven’t bloomed yet. Nearby trees of the same variety have blooming flowers and don’t display the curled leaves or yellowing. I’ve attached pictures. I’ve watered each plant twice this week with 10 litres per plant each time but it hasn’t made a difference. Should I feed them?

[image: curling leaves]
[image: yellowing leaves]
[image: flowers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided they were planted in good, fertile soil, they shouldn't really need feeding, but a handful or three of Growmore granules lightly turned in at the base of the shrubs might be helpful. Also a mulch of composted materials (composted manure or good garden compost) spread round the base (but not touching the trunks) would be helpful, but apply that when the soil is moist. Basically, though, because they were quite mature when first planted, they will need copious amounts of water if the weather is warm/dry for their first two years, this year being the most critical.

Some leaf yellowing is normal for Prunus laurocerasus; like all evergreens, they do lose leaves, they just do it year round instead of in one go in autumn. As for flowering, usual flowering time for these is early to mid May - it looks like the flower buds are healthy, and will open when the time is right. However, if they go short of water, you may find the flowers abort and don't open at all.